# MySql Hebrew decode

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, hebrew

In my data base I have some text encoded like '×"×ª×™×™×¨×•×' (Hebrew text)

How can I put in a $var the **original Hebrew** characters ?

I tried :

```
$var = utf8_decode($row['title']);
if ( preg_match("/(?:\p{Hebrew}+)/iu", $var) ) {
            echo 'Hebrew';  
        }
```

but this is not working ! With $var = 'המפורסם' that works fine ;))

Thanks for your help...

Comment: Encodings are always next to the data itself. In case you pass the wrong information in that parallel-channel, the data might become broken when processed, for example in a storage operation with your database. In that case, you first need to fix the data again before you can use it. To not make this fixing necessary all the time, you first of all need to fix the broken processing that makes the database either store or retrieve the wrong data. All these processings are not part of your code-example so all we can practically suggest you is to close against a reference question so far.

Comment: possible duplicate of [UTF-8 all the way through](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through)

Comment: What encoding is used in your DB?

Comment: @Edouard : The field Collation is utf8_unicode_ci

Comment: Do you manage to view your data correctly at some point?

Comment: [utf8_decode()](http://php.net/utf8_decode) converts from `ISO-8859-1` but such encoding is designed for Western Europe (Spanish, French, Italian...). There's no way you can fit Hebrew in ISO-8859-1! Do you mean that your data is corrupted and are asking for a way to fix it?

Comment: In my database characters are well encoding. I just need to back to the original Hebrew characters to be able to use the regex.

Comment: @Chris - Your question clearly states that data looks like `×"×ª×™×™×¨×•×` in your DB. You should edit your question and clarify that. Whatever, if you are using `utf8_unicode_ci` then this question is a dupe as hakre points out.

Comment: @Álvaro : OK. I point out in my question that the text looks like '×"×ª×™×™×¨×•×' in my DB field ;))

Comment: @Chris - So "In my database characters are well encoding" and "text looks like '×"×ª×™×™×¨×•×' in my DB field" at the same time? Aren't those contradictory statements?

Comment: @Álvaro : Sorry I thought this was well encoding in the DB !!!
I have a form where people write in Hebrew. I send the form via Ajax and this is the way the Characters are in the DB field '×"×ª×™×™×¨×•×'. What I have to do to insert 'המפורסם' and not '×"×ª×™×™×¨×•×' ?

Comment: Just to let you know I solve my problem by adding mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8' COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci'"). Now texts in DB fields are in Hebrew and I can use my preg_match above ;))

Answer (score 0):

## PHP

You should be aware of [Multibyte String functions](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php).

### MySQL

[mysql_set_character_set()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/mysql-set-character-set.html):  set the default character set for the current connection